# Get the client's operating system's name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to get the client's operating system's name (i.e Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows Vista).

Comment: Read my answer below for the most updated solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities browse = Request.Browser;
string platform = browse.Platform;
```

Comment: I believe this results `WinNT` on XP, Vista and 7. Not very useful.

Comment: It is better to use nuget UAParser mentioned below.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Request.Browser.Platform`, and the version is in `Request.UserAgent`

Comment: @abatishchev the Request.UserAgent gave me 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)'

Comment: @aaa: Actually that's Tejo's answer. Windows 6.1 means Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: thanks for info..Windows 6.1 means Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. The link provided by @Waqas helped me resolving my issue..

Answer (score 4):

I installed a cool tool named: https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp
 that parse the user agent to OS,Browser,Browser version etc...
[Link to Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UAParser/).

And this is how used it:

```
 public static string GetUserOS(string userAgent)
        {
            // get a parser with the embedded regex patterns
            var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
            ClientInfo c = uaParser.Parse(userAgent);
            return c.OS.Family;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
var platform = os.Platform.ToString();
var version = os.Version.ToString();
var servicePack = os.ServicePack.ToString();
```

You can also find with the help of user agent.

```
String userAgent = Request.UserAgent;

         if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.3") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 8.1
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.2") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 8
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.1") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 7
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.0") > 0)
         {
             //Windows Vista
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.2") > 0)
         {
             //Windows Server 2003; Windows XP x64 Edition
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.1") > 0)
         {
             //Windows XP
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.01") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 2000, Service Pack 1 (SP1)
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 5.0") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 2000
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 4.0") > 0)
         {
             //Microsoft Windows NT 4.0
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Win 9x 4.90") > 0)
         {
             //Windows Millennium Edition (Windows Me)
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows 98") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 98
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows 95") > 0)
         {
             //Windows 95
         }
         else if (userAgent.IndexOf("Windows CE") > 0)
         {
             //Windows CE
         }
         else
         {
             //Others
         }
```